# Is there a predefined webpart called CAPTCHA webpart?

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

How would I go about creating a CAPTCHA plugin for the framework Kentico CMS 7.0?

Is there a predefined webpart called CAPTCHA webpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few form controls of CAPTCHA type. Navigate to Site manager -> Development -> Form controls and filter out CAPTCHA controls. You'll find e.g. "logic captcha" or "text captcha". You can use those controls e.g. in forms (this is typical usage) or anywhere else (just see properties of particular control).

If you want to prevent robots posting to your forms edit the form, add a text field and select CAPTCHA of your choice as a form control.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the built in CAPTCHA controls, you can also build your own [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) control rather easily. The instructions are listed on [this Kentico DeveNet forum post](http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums/f45/fp3/t17216/Google-reCAPTCHA-in-a-BizForm-tutorial.aspx). Note that for step 5, instead of using the code listed in the first post, use the code in my reply to the initial post ('Gavin_Paolucci-Kleinow-URMC.Rochester - 1/4/2013 11:05:53 AM' since I can't link to that individual post in the thread).