# How to Add CAPTCHA ControlForm into page

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I found CAPTCHA Control in Kentico and it's Types (Simple - Logic - Text) CAPTCHA

Now, how can I add it inside WebZone?

I tried using it as a WebPart but it's not like webparts can be added inside Zone
What Steps Should i Follow?

```
</div>
<div id="MessageForm">
<div class="feedback_form">
<h2>Feedback</h2>
<div class="feedback_input">
<span>Name</span><input class="text_feedback" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="feedback_input">
<span>Email</span><input class="text_feedback" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="feedback_input">
<span>Subject</span><input class="text_feedback" type="text" value="" />
</div>
<div class="feedback_input  Message">
<span>Message</span><textarea class="Message_input" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="feedback_input">
<input class="send"  type="submit" value="" />
<img src="image/Captcha.png" />
<input class="type_Captcha"  type="text" value="Enter Captcha ... " />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

That's what i'm trying to do.

Replace the html Code inside my form for this areaZone and put customize webpart if available to do the required function.

Comment: First, tell us what are you trying to do. Are you trying to protect some online form or forum or blog comment section? If yes, you can add the form control into a field as I previusly described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172532/is-there-a-predefined-webpart-called-captcha-webpart. If no, tell us more about your scenario. CAPTCHA control cannot exist on its own, it has to somehow be part of html form.

Comment: i recently add snapshot for what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

You can use out of the box functionality called Forms. See "Creating a new form" in [documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/bizforms_module_overview.htm) and just add CAPTCHA as one of the fields. Then use On-line form web part on your web site. That's all.